# Why will this function not open my file?

Tags: python, file

```
def open_file(filename):
    file_open= open(filename,"r")
    return file_open
```

When I try and call the function I get the following results:

```
>>> open_file(random.txt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    open_file(random.txt)
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Comment: Pass the parameter as a string: `open_file('random.txt')`

Comment: If you're trying to write a string literal (such as a filename), it needs to be in quotes; e.g. `open_file('random.txt')`

Comment: so when I call the function the file name needs to be in quotes everytime?

Comment: You had a mistake in passing the parameter. Beside the function returns a file object not content of it

Comment: @JCSenkpiel you quotes something when you want to pass it as literally that string. If you want to call the function with a variable holding the file name you don't need to quote it. `x = "random.txt"` then you can call it `open_file(x)` noticed no quotes? since it's a variable?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
open_file('random.txt')
```

Strings in Python need to be quoted.
`random` is being interpreted as an object, and is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot quotes:

```
open_file('random.txt')
```

python thinks random is an object, which obviously you didn't define. The quotes make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to input the filename as a string; here's how it must be done:

```
>>> open_file('random.txt')
```

> note that your function works just fine, all you need to do is call it properly.